# Should I revert appended answer to question?

Tags: discussion, edits, moderation

Chronology:

- question of type "*how to do?*" asked Mar 20 '09
- low approved, "*don't do it*" answer 8 minutes later
- well approved "*how to do it*" answer two years later on Apr 25 '11
- well approved "*Wikipedia does it everywhere*" comment on  May 14 '11
- One year later, on Aug 23 '12, a moderator [appends the "*don't do it*" answer to the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/667429/revisions)

Should I revert, flag or leave it?

Comment: he got the *Sheriff* badge on Nov 22 '12, so he was a moderator at the time of the edit.

Comment: As far as I can see, it is not a "don't do it" answer, but merely a very long comment on the question that the OP happened to post as an answer. Appending it to the question seems entirely sensible.

Comment: @duplode, oh, and then the comment was deleted I guess?

Comment: The (non-)answer was indeed deleted at about the same time the edit was made. The text of the deleted answer was added verbatim to the question through the edit. [10k+ link to it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/667587/2751851).